# Cannot use "postOfficeBox" in User Profile Synchronization Service

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service

I would like to use the "P. O. Box"-AD-attribute (according to http://www.selfadsi.de/user-attributes-w2k8.htm it is named "postOfficeBox") in SharePoint.
Unluckily i cannot find the according entry in the user profile synchronization service.
There is a "(M)postOfficeBox" entry when switching to "string (multi-value)", but after a full crawl it shows that 0 users are using this attribute.

The UPS is up and running and i am able to map other attributes like company.

What steps would i have to take to make postOfficeBox available in the UPS?

Answer (score 1):

I made a mistake in configuring the mapping. I marked "Replicable" as true, thus the synchronization process threw an error each time I tried to synchronize.

In order to debug such issues I found it to be very helpful to use the FIM Client in

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\14.0\Synchronization Service\UIShell\miisclient.exe
```

It is recommended to only VIEW the process of synchronization with this client in SharePoint scenarios!